# breaking out of structured block in openmp

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I am trying to write a program using openmp in which the structure block is a while loop.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(x)
while(condition){

}
```

I have to decide upon the way to code the condition on which any thread would stop. I need to know if it is proper to have a break statement in the while loop.

Comment: This isn't really possible with OpenMP. Parallel loops can only be done on loops who's trip-counts can be determined prior to starting the loop. So OpenMP restricts this to for-loops with very specific constraints on the loop conditions. If you have a loop that could randomly break out at any time, then it's not possible to parallelize different iterations because you never know which is the last iteration.

Comment: I am not trying to distribute the iteration between different threads. All the threads will be executing all the iterations.

Comment: Oh. If you're trying to parallelize within each iteration, then you put the parallel region inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is a bit incomplete. You said "**Condition on Which any thread would stop**", but what about the after math:

1. Rest of the Threads should also exit.
2. Rest of the Threads should continue till they match the condition.

Case 1:

```
bool abort = 0;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(x) private(abort)
{
   while(!abort)
   {
      // The work you need to do.
      #pragma omp critical
      {
          if(condition==false)
          {
             abort = 1; 
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Case 2:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(x)
{
    while(condition)
   {
        // The work you need to do.
   }
}
```

Comment: cancellation,which you would need, is a relatively new feature.  For example, it would (apparently) require gcc version 6.1 or newer, and is unlikely ever to show up in Microsoft OpenMP.

Answer (score 4):

I think that is it better to use omp cancellation.

The code would look similar to this one.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{       
    while(true) {
        #pragma omp cancellation point parallel

        // Do the heavy work

        if(condition==false) {
            #pragma omp cancel parallel
        }
    }
}
```