# C++ OpenMP exit while loop inside a parallel for

Tags: c++, while-loop, multiprocessing, openmp, nested-loops

I use Visual Studio 2010 and OpenMP on a Windows 7 machine. I've written the following code snipplet:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int jj=0;jj<2;jj++){
MSG msg;
// do something in parallel for jj
int i_loopcounter = 0;
bool b_continue = true;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)&&b_continue){
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    i_loopcounter++;    
    if(i_loopcounter==50){
        b_continue = false;
        //abort(); <- ugly, since a window appears  
        //exit(0); <- rest of the code is not executed
        //break;  <- not allowed
        //goto end; <- not allowed
    }
}
end:;
// do some other stuff in parallel for jj
} //end of parallel for
```

My problem is:

If I use the `b_continue` variable, the first while loop which reaches the abort condition causes the program to hang-up (Is this a race condition, which I don't see?), as a result the program does not execute the rest of the code.

So how can I get this working?

I've tried the solution suggested in [breaking out of structured block in openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858499/breaking-out-of-structured-block-in-openmp) but this does not change the situation.

The selfdestucting while loop is needed to trigger a download of a file from a piece of hardware. After it is finished the program should do some work on that file. Before I started to parallelise the code it worked well using the break statement in the while loop.

Thanks for any comments, which give me a hint to solve this issue.

**Update:** I now changed the code to

```
int i_loopcounter = 0;
    while(_i_NoDownloads!=2){
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        i_loopcounter++;    
        if(_b_control){
            cout<<i_loopcounter <<" of Thread "<<omp_get_thread_num()<<endl;
        }       
    }
```

The global variable `_i_NoDownloads` counts the number of downloaded files, if it reaches 2 the message loops are no longer needed. However, even with this changes the behavior of the program does not change, despite the fact that, the while loop now does not necessarily 50 iterations. I think that the problem is to desturct the message loops simultaneously.

**Update 2:** After Reading a lot about the concept of Windows Messages, I found a solution which works. The reason why the parallel section did not finish is the behavior of GetMessage.

Again, thanks a lot, to anybody who contributed to this issue.

Cheers
TL

Comment: The same message loop running in different OpenMP threads? I can't event think how this can behave. Message loop belongs to one thread only. You need to redesign your code completely.

Comment: From some cout command, which displays i_loopcounter and omp_get_thread_num(), it seems that there are two message loops since I get both thread numbers (0 and 1)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot abort in a parallel region,
http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/06/29/breaking-out-of-loops-in-openmp/

Possible solution,
http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1431

Comment: Thank you, for the link, but I end up with the same result as in the problem description. Generally I do not want to abort the parallel region. I want to exit the while loop such that the parallel for can finish, if I do not set an abort contition for the while loop, the program will never terminate. At the moment I'm thinking of a solution by using sections. Here I would have three threads, 2 for the parallel which send a message to the third thread which handles them and terminates after some time. But I don't know if it works. The message handling is not quite clear to me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to use a small and hard-coded number of iterations:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int jj = 0; jj < 2; jj++){
 /* ... */
} //end of parallel for
```

you may possibly want to explore solutions based on the `sections` directive:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp sections
  {
#pragma omp section
    {
      /* jj = 0 */
    }         
#pragma omp section
    {
      /* jj = 1 */
    }             
  } // End sections
#pragma omp single
  { 
    /* While loop */
  }
  /* ... */      
} // End parallel
```